# Iterating over Sitecore bucket items

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7

I have an item on the Sitecore tree that has bucket items, so they can't be accessed with the normal hierarchical API.

Is there an example of how to loop over the bucket items in a certain bucket programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you are trying to loop through the items?  I think you'll be better off utilizing search in order to find the items you are looking for.  I'd recommend you check out Sitecore's documentation for more information on this: [Developer's Guide to Item
Buckets and Search](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/developer%27s_guide_to_item_buckets_and%20search_sc7-a4.pdf)

Comment: there is a reason, I need to import all the items in the bucket to a different system on a scheduled task

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response to Craig Taylor, I would say you should perform an index search to get all the items from the bucket, perform a search and then you can loop through the results.

Craig pointed out this document [Developer's Guide to Item Buckets and Search](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/developer%27s_guide_to_item_buckets_and%20search_sc7-a4.pdf) which should be useful.

Strictly speaking, buckets just hide the underlying tree structure, and search works just like anywhere else in Sitecore. You can use the default indexes `sitecore_web_index` / `sitecore_master_index` or a custom index. The bucket content will be included so long as it's is within one of the specified index locations.

If you're not familiar with searching in Sitecore, this article is a good place to begin: [Sitecore 7 Search – Quick Start Guide](http://coreblimey.azurewebsites.net/sitecore-7-search-quick-start-guide/)

Comment: do you know where I can find an example of indexing bucket items?

Answer (score 1):

```
    public List<T> GetAllItemsFromBucket(string bucketPath)
    {
        var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("content_index");
        using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
        {
            var results = context.GetQueryable<T>().Where(x => x.Path.StartsWith(bucketPath)).ToList();
            foreach (var result in results) _service.Map(result);
            return results;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Sitecore is considered as Items. So even if you have Configured Item Buckets and if you are trying to access or iterate it programmatically you could perform this task in normal way.

If you are searching an item in the Item buckets then probably you could use the below code to search the contents.

```
var itemBuckets= Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(bucketPath);
  if (itemBuckets!= null && BucketManager.IsBucket(itemBuckets))
  {     
     using (var searchContext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(itemBuckets as IIndexable).CreateSearchContext())
    {
        var result = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem().Where(x => x.Name == itemName).FirstOrDefault();
        if(result != null)
            Context.Item = result.GetItem();
    }
  }
```

Checkout my blog for Complete details on [Configuring Sitecore Item Buckets](https://itsmycode.com/convert-sitecore-items-into-an-sitecore-item-bucket/)

Comment: I tried this and it does not work. You cannot cast an item to IIndexable. Would have been nice tho.